# Why I get different permissions when I create a file with a different group and how can I configure that?

Tags: permissions, users, group

When I create files with a different group I see that the permissions are different

I did this as root:

```
groupadd stack
useradd stack1
gpasswd stack  (choose a password)
su stack1
touch testfile
I did ls -l and I see permissions rw-rw-r--
newgrp stack (enter the password I previously created for that group)
touch test2
I did ls -l and I see permissions of file test2 rw-r--r--
```

And where can I change that option, I think it has to do with umask but I'm not sure.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, `umask` decides the permission of the touched file. However `newgrp` should not change the umask. What is the output of `umask` before and after your `newgrp`?

Comment: @michas 0002 and 0022 respectively, you can test this by yourself.

Comment: I tested it. No change on my system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you know, the difference is due to the different umask values. When you create a file you specify the maximum permissions the file should have. For `touch` this would be `rw-rw-rw-`. The umask is then used to reduce the permissions.

In general you should use `su - stack1` to switch to a user.

newgrp is a difficult program to write. It typically is suid as it needs to manipulate the groups. Ideally it would be built into the shell like umask is, so it would alter the groups for the current process, but this is incompatible with it being suid. So typically it is a suid binary that prompts for the password, and if validation succeeds it will replace itself with a shell. This shell can run its startup code.

If your ~/.bashrc file has a umask command in it, either directly or indirectly, then that would explain the difference in values.